# Spring boot 1.5.2.Release - DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor does not remove default "ROLE_" prefix

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot application have defined DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor as mentioned in section 8.3 of Reference manual. Excerpt shown below:

```
public class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {
    @Override 
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) { 
        if (bean instanceof DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) { 
            ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null); 
        } 
    ....    // if statement for DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
    ....    // if statement for SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
    return bean;
}
```

The SecurityConfig class overrides configure(HttpSecurity) method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ....
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

However any @Secured method still requires "ROLE_" prefix, otherwise a 403 is received, mainly due to the default AccessDecisionManager's RoleVoter returning a 0

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Secured("ROLE_XXX")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue, or is using 'hasAuthority' the only way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `@EnableWebSecurity` from your class `SecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // your config
    }
}
```

If you use `@EnableWebSecurity`, the default config is turned off completely

> To switch off the default web application security configuration
>   completely you can add a bean with

It's not needed in your case. Method security however must be enabled if you want to use it like you did.

so I think your post processor isn't used at all, if you didn't to this manually someplace you haven't posted.